# Upload 5000+ html files to SharePoint Online for viewing and searching

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have 5000+ basic html files that contain knowledge from another database. Each file contains a title for weighted searching, some metadata, and bodies of text.

I'd like to upload these files to SharePoint so we can use SharePoint search functionality to rummage through this knowledge. My problem, however, is that SharePoint Online doesn't feel like rendering these files as an actual HTML page.

Is there a way to mass upload these files so they render as regular HTML and are searchable? I've tried changing the file extension to .aspx to no avail (granted I might be missing critical aspx tags that I'm not familiar with.

If needed, I can mass modify the files if another format would be better.

Comment: why not switch them to .txt? Do you need to browse to it, if most of the content is in the html file itself? To me it sounds like you really need search to work more than browsing to it, so I'd say (at least temporarily) change them all to .txt

Comment: That was my first thought, but my concern would be adding search weight on the title. Is there a way to solve this with a .txt?

Comment: since you are on sharepoint online, you'd need to change the ranking model -- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-ranking-model-by-using-the-Ranking-Model-Tuning-App-345be622-2f63-450c-bd65-869ce830b7c1?CTT=1&CorrelationId=5ce86646-136b-4afc-a59b-c8588aea32f3&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA104104860